# When applying PCA to images for CNN, do I have to give it the grayscale image?

Tags: image-processing, dataset, pca, image-compression

I am applying PCA to an image using compression. With the linear algebra techniques of [this paper](https://github.com/krishnr/PCA/blob/master/Lin_Alg_Project.pdf).

I am trying to reduce the dimensionality of a dataset, to make an object detector with a convolutional neural network.

It turns out I'm a bit confused, [in this algorithm](https://github.com/krishnr/PCA/blob/master/PCA.ipynb) and in others they always transform the image to grayscale. So I wonder: do I have to deliver the grayscale image to the convolutional neural network?

Or do I have to return it to its rgb form with its corresponding colors? If so, how do I return the rgb colors to the image?

This is the output result in grayscale with 300 components:
[image]

This is part of the code I used:

```
X = arr

# if RGB, convert to grayscale
if len(X.shape) > 2:
    X = np.mean(X,2)

# number of columns
n_components = np.size(X,axis=1)

dist = []
max_components = 350
step = 50
i = 1
n_columns = 3
n_images = max_components/step/n_columns + 1
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))

for n in range(0,max_components+step,step):
    e_vecs,proj,e_vals = principal_components(X, n)

    # Reconstructing original image from the projection
    Xr = np.dot(e_vecs,proj).T + np.mean(X,axis=0)

    # Distance between original and reconstruction
    dist.append(np.linalg.norm(X-Xr))

    #Download Image at n components
    if n==300:
      cv2.imwrite('gray.jpg', Xr)
      #break

    fig.add_subplot(n_images, n_columns, i)
    plt.imshow(Xr, cmap='Greys_r')
    #plt.axis('off')
    plt.title("n = %d" % n)

    i += 1
```

Summarizing the questions are:

1) When applying PCA in images, do I have to give the network the image in grayscale or colors?

2) If it is with colors, how do I get the colors back?

Comment: My opinion is to pass the Grayscale images to your neural network, and after training, if the results weren't so good, you can think again about colourizing them, you are using PCA to reduce dimensionality, adding colours will increase your dataset size three times.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you feeding the reconstructed image into the CNN?

Comment: @dhanushka I'm preparing the data for train the CNN. I want to reduce dimensionality from images. Through image compression.